# Implicit conversion hash to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting this error.

> "no implicit conversion of Hash into String"

this is my .rb file. can anyone suggest me with a solution.

```
def themify_colors
    if Store.Configurations['themify_colors'].present?
        @themify_colors = JSON.parse(Store.Configurations['themify_colors'])
    end
end
```

Comment: Your `Store.Configurations['themify_colors']` seems to already be a hash. In this case, just don't parse it.

Comment: Can you post contains of ``Store.Configurations``  here ? I would like to see the structure of it.

Comment: `@themify_colors ||= Store.Configurations['themify_colors']` as a function body would do.

Comment: See: [mcve]. Please provide enough information in your question for us to be able to answer it. In this case, we need to know what is `Store.Configurations['themify_colors']`?

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse only accepts string as argument and by default returns a Hash. But in your case you are already passing it Hash thats why JSON.parse is throwing error.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html

```
def themify_colors
    @themify_colors = Store.Configurations['themify_colors'] 
    @themify_colors = JSON.parse(@themify_colors) unless @themify_colors.is_a?(Hash)
end
```

Comment: Still does not fix the fact that the var is reassigned every time the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a conditional to avoid reassigning the variable and a check that that `Store.Configurations['themify_colors']` is a string before attemping to parse it.

```
def themify_colors
  unless @themify_colors
    config = Store.Configurations['themify_colors']
    @themify_colors = config.is_a?(String) ? JSON.parse(config) : config  
  end
  @themify_colors
end
```

Even at that its still less than perfect and a prime canidate for refactoring. Parsing config is something that more likely should be done in the initialization of the application - not in the getter that uses the value.